# Add listbox item to SQL Server columns as columns name

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, listbox

```
foreach (string LB in listBox1.Items)
{
    SqlCommand SCA = new SqlCommand("create table " + textBox3.Text + "("+ 
    listBox1.Items[].ToString()+")",SC1); 
    SCA.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

How to add all items using loop to add items on listbox.items to SQL Server columns for columns name only?

Example:

[image: use listbox items to create table like this, only columns name]

Comment: You can create a `DataTable` from listbox items and then use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create several tables with the same name in a loop. I suppose your code should look something like that:

```
// StringBuilder is better way to creating a string in a loop,
// because it doesn't allocate new string on each concatenation
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("create table ");
command.Append(textBox3.Text).Append("(");

string separator = "";

// It is better to give more descriptive names to variables
foreach (string columnName in listBox1.Items)
{
    // You forgot to specify column type
    command.Append(separator)
           .Append(columnName)
           .Append(" varchar(1000)");

    separator = ",";
}

command.Append(")");

// SqlCommand and SqlConnection implement IDisposable, 
// so it is better to wrap their instantiation by 'using' statement 
// in order to free corresponding resources
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(command.ToString(), SC1)) {
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: the '(.Append(separator);)' i replace to '(.Append(","))', if no the result will come out like this '({create table Table4(test1 varchar(1000)test2 varchar(1000),test3 varchar(1000),)})', no have comma on'(test1 varchar(1000)test2 varchar(1000))'.